# Sum minutes by day in SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, group-by, sum

I am currently working in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have 2 tables. `Table1` consists of `PartNumber` as `varchar`, `Time` as `smalldatetime`, and `Table2` consists of `Minutes` as `float`, `PartNumber` as `Varchar`, and `Sequence` as `int`.

I am trying to sum the minutes by day, there are multiple entries per day and they have a time stamp which includes time of day. I am trying to make a list of all the days over a date range where it will show me the total minutes per day.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT Sum([MINUTES]) as total, Time from Table1 left join 
Table2 on
Table1.PartNumber + '-' = Table2.PART_NUMBER
WHERE sequence = 25 AND [MINUTES] > 30 And partNumber IS NOT NULL
group by Time
```

This code shows each line item. For example I may have 3 entries from the date "2015-04-22" but my time stamps are "2015-04-22 13:42:00", "2015-04-22 10:21:00", and "2015-04-22 13:21:00." I need the code to add the minuets from all entries from "2015-04-22" and then show me that total over an amount of time  I can change.

Comment: Just cast your datetime column to a date and include that in your group by.

Comment: can you give me a link for casting date time?

Comment: Cast(YourDateTimeColumn as DATE)

Comment: How can i format my date to be YYYY-MM-DD and cut of the actual time stamp?

Comment: Are you familiar with BOL (Books online)? It is the documentation for sql server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx I would suggest NOT formatting in sql and do your formatting in the front end.

Comment: Can you please give us example of your data and the output what you are expecting?

Comment: I got it guys, sorry for going dark, I got busy with other stuff at work and I ended up putting this code down until today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [CONVERT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), like so:

```
SELECT 
    SUM([MINUTES]) AS total,
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), Time, 112) AS Time
FROM 
    Table1 
LEFT JOIN 
    Table2 
        ON Table1.PartNumber + '-' = Table2.PART_NUMBER
WHERE 
    sequence = 25
    AND [MINUTES] > 30 
    And partNumber IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY
    CONVERT(CHAR(8), Time, 112)
```

Do keep in mind that if you want parts with a **total** time > 30 minutes you need to move that to a `HAVING` clause. The `112` specifies ISO date format, e.g. 20150515.

Comment: please not that convert function Applies to: SQL Server (SQL Server 2008 through current version), Azure SQL Database.

Comment: This was perfect!! Sorry for the long wait time on the reply, i got busy at work and then the weekend hit me before I could get back to this code. Thanks a ton!